# Facebook Connect vs.Twitter OAuth - Security

Tags: security, facebook, oauth

I'm thinking about creating a web app where users may login via Facebook Connect or Twitter OAuth. I'm wondering how secure these logins are? Are there any security issues I should be concerned about? Thanks in advance for your advice and suggestions.

Comment: I've had concerns and asked a related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331180/is-it-possible-to-make-oauth-secure-on-ios

Answer (score 1):

They are both pretty solid.

Are you concerned about users of your web app exposing their private data or are you worried about your site being exploited due to these authentication methods?

Comment: +1 Thanks for the reply. I was wondering about both. I read somewhere about some security concerns but I'm currently not up to scratch with these security issues